# Zabbix SQLite3 Semaphore Errors

Tags: permissions, semaphore, zabbix

I've been having trouble getting Zabbix to work properly on a FreeBSD system using SQLite3 as the database. It works properly most of the time, but refreshing the frontend occasionally causes this error to appear:

```
SQLite3::query(): Unable to execute statement: database is locked [hosts.php:863 → CAPIObject->get() → CAPIObject->__call() → czbxrpc::call() → czbxrpc::callAPI() → call_user_func() → CTemplate->get() → DBselect() → SQLite3->query() in /usr/local/www/apache22/include/db.inc.php:445]
```

I've also noticed that this semaphore error appears in the server log every time the server restarts:

```
using configuration file: /usr/local/etc/zabbix22/zabbix_server.conf zabbix_server [42454]: php_sem_get(): failed for key 0x7a52f8e2: [13] Permission denied
```

I think this might have something to do with the permissions of the database file.

Currently the database file and the directory above it are owned by the user "www" and the group "zabbix" with 777 permissions. Is this what it should be?

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that you have a problem with semaphores in PHP. Try to compile PHP with --enable-sysvsem:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php

Reference: https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=43751